# how to make serializer for two models that dont have relation with each other

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

i am working on ecommerce shop and in my home page i want to return all the products and 7 images for the icons for the categories , my models.py is

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,decimal_places=2,null=False,blank=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20 ,blank=False, null=False ,default='none', choices=cat)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'product_photos/%y/%m/%d',null=True)

 class Category(models.Model):
        icon = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'icon',null=True)
```

and my serializers.py is

```
class ProductSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta :
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta :
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes ([AllowAny] , )
def home (request):
    p = Product.objects.filter(is_discount= 1).order_by('-pub_date')
    serializer = ProductSerializer(p,many=True)
    return Response (serializer.data)
```

how to return both the category and product in the same view , NOTE : my views.py is function based view

Comment: How can you search for the category of the product? Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: I added a list field in product his name is category and i search for this field

Comment: Where did you add? I can't see.